# How to intercept the paypal payment confirmation with Virtuamart 2 in joomla

Tags: joomla, paypal, e-commerce

i need to intercept the payment confirmation from paypal to my joomla site (with virtuamart 2), in other words i need to know which file is called after a successfully payment to add a snippet of code to update another database
Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtueMart 2.x all payment methods (and for that matter shipping methods) are handled by Joomla! plugins. So for payment plugins you will find the relevant file in:

`/plugins/vmpayment/paypal/`

Shipping plugins are in the similarly named:

`/plugins/vmshipment/` directory.